# Detecting outliers in a Pandas dataframe using a rolling standard deviation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, standard-deviation, outliers

I have a DataFrame for a fast Fourier transformed signal.

There is one column for the frequency in Hz and another column for the corresponding amplitude.

I have read a post made a couple of years ago, that you can use a simple boolean function to exclude or only include outliers in the final data frame that are above or below a few standard deviations.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':np.random.normal(size=200)})  # example dataset of normally distributed data. 
df[~(np.abs(df.Data-df.Data.mean())>(3*df.Data.std()))] # or if you prefer the other way around
```

The problem is that my signal drops several magnitudes (up to 10 000 times smaller) as frequency increases up to 50 000Hz. Therefore, I am unable to use a function that only exports values above 3 standard deviation because I will only pick up the "peaks" outliers from the first 50 Hz.

Is there a way I can export outliers in my dataframe that are above 3 rolling standard deviations of a rolling mean instead?

Comment: So I'm trying to add all the values that are filtered (larger than my mean+3SD) into another column in my dataframe before exporting. Right now they only show as true or false from `N1['Peaks'] = (N1['Cell 1-1'] > N1['Filter'])` Is there a way to get the numbers instead? The columns Cell 1-1 and Filter are just values for my data and filter.

Answer (score 9):

This is maybe best illustrated with a quick example.  Basically you're comparing your existing data to a new column that is the rolling mean plus three standard deviations, also on a rolling basis.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':np.random.normal(size=200)})

# Create a few outliers (3 of them, at index locations 10, 55, 80)
df.iloc[[10, 55, 80]] = 40.    

r = df.rolling(window=20)  # Create a rolling object (no computation yet)
mps = r.mean() + 3. * r.std()  # Combine a mean and stdev on that object

print(df[df.Data > mps.Data])  # Boolean filter
#     Data
# 55  40.0
# 80  40.0
```

To add a new column filtering only to outliers, with NaN elsewhere:

```
df['Peaks'] = df['Data'].where(df.Data > mps.Data, np.nan)

print(df.iloc[50:60])
        Data  Peaks
50  -1.29409    NaN
51  -1.03879    NaN
52   1.74371    NaN
53  -0.79806    NaN
54   0.02968    NaN
55  40.00000   40.0
56   0.89071    NaN
57   1.75489    NaN
58   1.49564    NaN
59   1.06939    NaN
```

Here [`.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) returns

> An object of same shape as `self` and whose corresponding entries are
>   from `self` where `cond` is True and otherwise are from `other`.