# Identifying rolling outliers and replacing them by backfill in timeseries data- Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, outliers, rolling-computation

I am plotting my data and I am getting local outliers as in the image below
[image]

I want to replace these outliers by bfill,  based on rolling mean of 120 days and not to remove these outliers instead.

My problem is that I cannot use an average mean as the value keeps increasing with time and outliers in for example 2013, are normal readings in 2018.

I have seen solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796265/detecting-outliers-in-a-pandas-dataframe-using-a-rolling-standard-deviation) but they don't provide a guide regarding how to replace these outliers (and I don't want to remove them completely)

Comment: Is it possible to share this data?

Comment: What you can do is in the first place decide a timewindow to use, then you compute the distribution of the values in that interval window, then you get a 95% confidence interval for the mean of that window, once you get the upper and lower bound, you can be pretty sure that your outlier is out of the confidence interval you just computed :) How does that sound? Getting the interval for the timewindow is not hard as you know the average values are approximately distributed as a Normal Variable with mean E(X) and variance Var(X)/n, this should do the trick.

Comment: @PankajJoshi The data is confidential, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Well the answer you linked gets you most of the way. Choose a number of rolling standard deviations outside of the rolling mean for a period that makes sense, then mark them as `NaN` and bfill them, something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':np.random.normal(size=200)})
df.iloc[[10, 55, 80]] = 40. 
r = df.rolling(window=20)
mps_up, mps_low = r.mean() + 3 * r.std(), r.mean()  -  3 * r.std()
df.loc[~df['Data'].between(mps_low.Data, mps_up.Data), 'Data'] = np.NaN
df['Data'] = df['Data'].fillna(method='bfill')
```

This should do the trick!

Comment: Yes but this will wipe out just the upper outliers not the others